# Project Versioning - CI/CD - Jenkins - AEM

Tags: jenkins, aem

AEM muti-module project has `pom.xml` at each module level. Version can we changed at that level, new build shows the artifacts with updated version.

With versions, there would be a new AEM Package created for each version. We would want to uninstall/delete the old package before installing new version.

Question is, how can we handle the uninstallation/deletion part of old package (new package to be installed is of different version) in CI-CD job? We could think of following solutions

1. Query the list of packages to get the version and use that to uninstall.
2. Pass version as parameter to Jenkins Job in "Build with Parameters". But automatic build trigger on code check-in could have issue.

Has anyone faced similar situation? Please share if there is best practice which is followed for AEM CI-CD jobs for handling different release versions.

Answer (score 1):

Querying the list of packages is your best option I think. You can collect any previous version of your package then, no matter when you deployed that specific package to that server the last time.

An alternative option might be to delete the package immediately after installing it, but I fear there might be lots of problems waiting for you then: 
Some packages need a restart, you may not delete the package to early, ...

As I said, I would go for the querying solution.

Comment: Yes, deleting package immediately after installing might not be good option. As filters of package might differ in new version, we would not have a way to handle un-installation.

Comment: Would un-installation of packages be required? If we want to do away with un-installation part and keep installing new packages by overwriting packages, would that be fine? Is there a general best practice to uninstall old package before installing new package? The AEM package manger, OSGi handles version on installation (new version is shown in package manager and OSGi console) of new version, just that /etc/packages would contain all packages.

Comment: That mainly depends on your repository. Big packages waste a lot of space if you keep all the old versions. In some projects we used weekly cleanup jobs on our dev instances that deleted the old packages.